# Layout width css

Tags: css

I can't fit all the images in one line.
Images are 210px wide, no margin, no padding no border and the container is 1050px wide. No margin, no padding, no border, so 210x5 = 1050px, should fit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ejercicio 9</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        #bolas{
            margin: auto auto;
            width: 1050px;
            }

        .bolas_billar{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            /*
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -85px;
            */
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bolas">
        <img id="bola7" class="bolas_billar" src="./images/bola7.jpeg" alt="Bola billar 7" width="210" height="170">
            <img id="bola8" class="bolas_billar" src="./images/bola8.jpeg" alt="Bola billar 8" width="210" height="170">
        <img id="bola9" class="bolas_billar" src="./images/bola9.jpeg" alt="Bola billar 9" width="210" height="170">
        <img id="bola10" class="bolas_billar" src="./images/bola10.jpeg" alt="Bola billar 10" width="210" height="170">
        <img id="bola13" class="bolas_billar" src="./images/bola13.jpeg" alt="Bola billar 13" width="210" height="170">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2mv94vm/

Comment: use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `font-size:0` to the main container `#bolas`. If you want some text inside the container then specify the font-size separately:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#bolas {
    margin: auto auto;
    width: 1050px;
    font-size:0; // Added
}
.bolas_billar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x2mv94vm/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` to float them next to each.

```
.bolas_billar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2mv94vm/4/

Answer (score 0):

add `"float:left"` property to `".bolas_billar"`

Answer (score 0):

```
body{margin:0;}
```

**add this code**

```
 #bolas{margin: 0 auto;width: 1050px;float:left;}

.bolas_billar{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
```